# My ion-list won't show the last item in the list when I scroll to the bottom

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I've created an ion-list with a header.  Once I added the header, the last item won't show when I scroll.

```html
    <ion-card style="height:400px;" class="groupList">
      <ion-header style="padding-top: 15px;">
          <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label>
            My Groups
          </ion-label>
          <ion-item lines="none" (click)="createGroup()">
            <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Create a Group</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
         </ion-list-header>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content scroll-y="true">

          <ion-list inset *ngFor="let group of myGroups; index as i; trackBy: trackByCreated">
            <ion-item [ngSwitch]="group.groupPic" (click)="goToGroupPage(group)">
              <ion-avatar *ngSwitchDefault slot="start">
                  <img [src]="group.groupPic"/>    
              </ion-avatar> 
              <ion-avatar *ngSwitchCase="'false'">
                  <img src="assets/img/add-an-image.png"/>    
              </ion-avatar> 
              <div style="padding-left: 5px;">
                <ion-label>
                    <h6>{{group.groupName}}</h6>
                </ion-label>
              </div>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-card>
```

[image: List]

It looks fine from chrome in localhost, but when I deploy to an actual Android phone the last item can't be seen.

Comment: I tried moving the *ngFor to the ion-item but when I do that then the headers are no longer fixed.

Comment: Actually what I noticed is that the header is scrollable. So when I move the header up then I can view the last item of the list

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same issue that I resolved adding an empty item at the end of the list with the attribute: `lines="none"` so that i will not even see the "ion-item's lines"
like this:
`<ion-item lines="none"></ion-item>`

By the way I think that it's just a ionic bug